# What exposure changes do I need to make when shooting with a teleprompter?

Tags: video, video-recording, iphone

As background, I have a **very** low budget setup, complete with using an iPhone 6 as my camera (with Filmic Pro as the software, so I can manually change things like exposure and focus). I made a teleprompter which has been working for me out of a cardboard box (coated on the inside with black tape) and an iPad (since I'm reading song lyrics, I don't need an operator). I used to be able to get video that was good enough quality for my purposes. I am shooting with Cowboy Studio umbrella lights in my garage.

My question is this: since adding the makeshift teleprompter, the video became darker and much grainier. I think it's because it's basically shooting through a black tunnel, and I have to crop the edges off. Within Filmic Pro, I have manual access to ISO and shutter speed, as well as a separate "Exposure Compensation" which seems to change the previous two values. How can I remove the darkness and graininess? I've tried increasing the ISO or decreasing the shutter speed, but my video ended up looking like badly done stop-motion animation. Did I go too far? Do I need to change the lighting setup?

[image: Setup from rear]
This is my setup from the rear, including both lights, the backdrop, and the cameraphone tripod and box-prompter.

[image: Setup from side 1]
This is my setup from the side, showing distance from cameraphone/tripod to microphone, which is where the talent (me) stands.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the setup? Are you using a beam splitter (two way mirror)?

Comment: I'll try to get a picture tomorrow. I am using plain glass from a picture frame, not tinted or anything.

Comment: Okay, I added two pictures. I took a third one which shows more closely how the two tripods and the box-prompter are positioned, but I don't have high enough reputation to post three and I'm not sure exactly which part of the setup will help the most.

Comment: I can't really see it clearly enough, but why do you need the box and the glass? Why not just put the iPad as close to the iPhone as you can without the rig?

Comment: Without the reflection, the talent wouldn't be looking at the lens, or camera, and that would be noticeable.

Comment: Then you should be using a [beamsplitter](http://www.tiffen.com/listec_prompting_simplified.html) instead of regular glass. Regular glass is not optically designed for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand why shooting with a camera through regular glass would affect the exposure.

Comment: I think it is because the reflection is acting as filter that is blocking the light. A beamsplitter is optically designed to reduce the light to the camera in a very specific way. A reflection on regular glass, doesn't have those same properties.